# JPanel removeAll not working like it should

Tags: java, swing

Problem: the buttons aren't being removed with lPanel.bListPanel.removeAll() included in the code.

My goal: when the button is clicked, I need the old buttons to disappear and a new list of buttons to populate.

Note: this button listener is in a separate class from the lPanel.

Thanks!

RoPanel class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class RoPanel extends JPanel {
    public LPanel lPanel;
    public RPanel rPanel;
    private Ly l;
    private ArrayList<JButton> bButtonList;
    private JTextField newLoadField;
    private JButton theButton;
    public String bText;
    private Border simpleBorder;

  public RoPanel() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    simpleBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY);
    l = new Ly();
    lPanel = new LPanel();
    rPanel = new RPanel();
    this.setBorder(simpleBorder);
    this.add(lPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(rPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    titleBooks = new ArrayList();

    lPanel.getLoadButton();
    lPanel.getLoadButton().addActionListener(new LoadButtonListener());

    newLoadField = lPanel.getLoadField();

    bookButtonList = new ArrayList();
    bookText = new String();
}


private class LoadButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String loadStringfile = newLoadField.getText();
        l.loadFromCSV(loadStringfile);

        lPanel.bListPanel.removeAll();

        // for loop that creates buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            BButton b = new BButton();

            bButtonList.add(theButton);
            lPanel.bListPanel.add(theButton);
        }

        lPanel.bListPanel.revalidate();
        lPanel.bListPanel.repaint();
    }
  }
}
```

LPanel class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.*;

  public class LPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField loadField;
   private JButton loadButton;
   private Border simpleBorder;
   private Border lowerBorder;
   JPanel bListPanel;
   JPanel importPanel;

  public LPanel() {

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    simpleBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY);
    lowerBorder = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);
    bListPanel = new JPanel();
    bListPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bListPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    importPanel = new JPanel();
    this.add(importPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // create a jscrollpane that contains all buttons
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setLocation(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(bListPanel);
    this.add(scrollPane);

    // loadfield and load button for iPanel
    loadField = new JTextField();
    loadField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 25));
    importPanel.add(loadField);
    loadButton = new JButton();
    loadButton.setText("Load");
    importPanel.add(loadButton);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi , is'nt it a refresh issue ? what happen if youresize the frame ?(this should force paint occured)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, the code is being reached. And I actually made a mistake when I posted originally. The problem is the buttons are not being removed by the removeAll().

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec When I re-size the frame nothing changes. I have also confirmed that the code is being reached.

Comment: [mcve] would clarify much. Having stated that, do consider using 1) a CardLayout, or 2) if the number of buttons don't change, then swap the Button `Action`s.

Comment: Is the instance of `lPanel.bListPanel` the same instance that's on the screen? See Hovercraft's comment - you are going to need to provide more context to your question before you get answer which isn't "guess work"

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Apologies for not including the code from the lPanel class. Would you recommend trying a CardLayout on the bListPanel? Also, the number of buttons does change.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm pretty sure the instances are the same, but I don't know how to verify that.

Comment: Please re-read the [mcve] requirements, as if followed correctly, they can help you get an answer quickly (if it is what is important to you)

Comment: removeAll() should work without any problem.probably once you call removeAll() , it might be the same button count that you added to the panel. in that case you can not see any difference. simply this is a bug in your code , you may debug and find out the problem

Comment: @hunter removeAll() actually does work if I move it down below the for loop that creates the buttons. If I run it with removeAll() below the for loop that creates the buttons, the buttons don't show up at all. If I run it with removeAll() above the for loop, the buttons don't disappear before creating new ones.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've don't my best to include all relevant code, but not too much.